# SQL query showing different answers while executing in SQL Editor and through Java

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I need to get the number of days in a month from the Register table.
Im using the following SQL Query :

`SELECT DateTo::Date-DateFrom::Date AS DaysInMonth FROM Register;`

While executing it in SQL Editor of PostgreSQL Im getting the following result :
[image]

While executing the same through java code Im getting the result as `29 days` instead of `29`
Im adding the java code here

```
sql = " SELECT DateTo::Date-DateFrom::Date AS DaysInMonth FROM Register; "                  
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;                
    try {
        pstmt = DB.prepareStatement(sql, null);
        pstmt.setInt(1, payReg.getC_Period_ID());
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();                      
        while (rs.next()){                          
            System.out.println(rs.getString("DaysInMonth"));
        }
    }catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

What may be the reason..?
I need to get just `29` from the java execution. How do I get it..?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: For calculating **days between two timestamps**, [consider this closely related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071630/postgresql-date-difference) - which is more sophisticated than to `get the number of days in a month` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..
`DATE_PART('days',DATE_TRUNC('month', DateTo) - DATE_TRUNC('month', Datefrom)) as DaysInMonth`

Comment: Thank you Sreekuttan. Its working properly, but what may be the problem while executing it through java.?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
rs.getInt("DaysInMonth")
```

Instead of

```
rs.getString("DaysInMonth")
```

As you are expecting an Integer.

Comment: It will throw an Exception saying "bad value for int : 29 days"

Answer (score 0):

Postgres certainly returns an `integer` when subtracting two `dates`. It looks like the cast did not happen. I suspect that **`::`** in the PostgreSQL specific syntax `DateTo::Date` has special meaning in your client. Try the SQL [**standard syntax for casting**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS):

Also demonstrating better ways to ...

> ... get the number of days in a month

```
EXTRACT(day FROM cast(DATE_TRUNC('month'
                                  ,now() + interval '1 month') AS date) - 1);
```

Better yet, use this **simpler and faster expression** that doesn't need a cast at all:

```
EXTRACT(day FROM DATE_TRUNC('month', now()) + interval '1 mon - 1 day');
```

Set [`log_statement = ALL`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-STATEMENT) temporarily and check in the Postgres DB logs what the server actually gets.