# Substract an hour from date SQL

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I have an entity with a `date` property represented as a `String` (I can't change it to Date or Timestamp).I need to get all newest records (not older than an hour).
I have a SQL query that returns the last (youngest) record, now I need to substract an hour from it somehow:

```
SELECT p FROM Invoice p WHERE date >= ((SELECT MAX(date) FROM Invoice)
```

it's Java and Posgresql. Can this be done using SQL when date is represented as a String?

Comment: What is format of a date there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL date difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071630/postgresql-date-difference)

Comment: You need to [parse it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296725/parse-date-in-mysql) then use [`DATE_SUB`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020162/how-to-subtract-3-hours-from-a-datetime-using-sql). Without storing the data as a date of some sort, this will be **horribly** slow.

Comment: format od the date is:  "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"

Comment: @BoristheSpider: there is no `date_sub` in Postgres

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT p, to_timestamp(p.data, 'YYYYMMDD HH12MI') - interval '1 hour' new_dt
FROM Invoice p WHERE date >= ((SELECT MAX(date) FROM Invoice)
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html

You will have to modify your date format pattern for your to_timestamp. I don't know what format your DB has it in.

Comment: ERROR:  conflicting values for "mm" field in formatting string
DETAIL:  This value contradicts a previous setting for the same field type. DB example: 2015/03/11 12:55:55

Comment: Did you update 'YYYYMMDD HH12MI' to the same format that you have in your DB?

Comment: Yes I did:      'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss;

Comment: Postgre has its own date format.  SimpleDateFormat does not work in there.  Check our the functions-formatting.html link.  Try this out: YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS

Answer (score 0):

In java its possible by parsing.but it is not possible in sql,because the datatype you are getting the date is String.

Comment: would String comparison in SQL actually work?                              SELECT p FROM Invoice p WHERE date >= :lastHour                   assuming lastHour is properly parsed String (with one hour substracted)

Answer (score 0):

assuming date is a column name,

```
select * from Invoice where "date"::date > now()-'1 hour'::interval
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`to_date()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html) to convert the string to an actual `date`.
While being at it: your query to get the latest row can be improved, too:

```sql
SELECT *
     , to_date(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') - interval '1 hour' AS ts
FROM   Invoice p
ORDER  BY date DESC NULLS LAST
LIMIT  1;
```

Assuming ISO format. Either way, your text representation has to *work* for the sort order, or you need to do more.

Subtracting an `interval` from a `date` results in a `timestamp` automatically.

Don't select `p`, that's the table alias and would get you the whole row as single column instead of individual columns.

`ORDER BY` / `LIMIT 1` is faster and more reliable for the purpose. Your construct could return multiple rows.

You should have an index on `date` to make this fast.

You should still store this as **date**, not as string. Even if you say you can't.

And don't use basic type names as column names.